# Printing Mariadb AuditLogs created with Docker-Compose to syslog

Tags: docker-compose, mariadb

I created a Mariadb with docker-compose. However, when I want audit logs to be written to syslog instead of file in the config, no audit log is written. Below I share the docker-compose yml file and audit sections in my.cnf. Is there a point that I overlooked or did something wrong?

docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mariadb:10.11.6
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE=1
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data/mysql/log/audit:/var/log/mysql
```

my.cnf

```
plugin_load_add = server_audit
server_audit=FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT
server_audit_logging=ON
server_audit_output_type=syslog
server_audit_events=connect,query
server_audit_query_log_limit=10000
server_audit_file_rotate_size=1000000
server_audit_file_rotate_now=ON
server_audit_file_rotations=5
```